# Update double nested array mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the below document which contains double nested array format. I have to update the "level" field to "Senior Engineer" when the "someKey":"somevalue" and "Company":"Company1" and "Name":"Nandhi".

**Document**

```
    { 
        "_id" : "777", 
        "someKey" : "someValue", 
        "someArray" : [
            {
                "Company" : "Company1", 
                "someNestedArray" : [
                    {
                        "name" : "Nandhi", 
                        "level" : "Junior Engineer"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "name" : "Rajan", 
                        "level" : "Senio Engineer"
                    }
                ]
            }], 
            {
                "Company" : "Company2", 
                "someNestedArray" : [
                    {
                        "name" : "Nandhi", 
                        "level" : "Junior Engineer"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "name" : "Rajan", 
                        "level" : "Senio Engineer"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

**Update Query I tried**

```
    db.Test123.updateOne(
    {"someKey" : "someValue","someArray.Company":"Company1"},
    {$set:{"someArray.$[someNestedArray].level":"Senior Developer"}},
    {arrayFilters:[{"someNestedArray.name":"Nandhi"}]}
    );
```

**Output Screenshot**

[image]

As you can seen that, the modifiedCount returns 0. Please advice on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define arrayFilter for every level of nesting, try:

```
db.Test123.update(
    { "someKey" : "someValue" },
    { "$set": { "someArray.$[someArrayDoc].someNestedArray.$[someNestedArrayDoc].level": "Senior Developer" } },
    { arrayFilters: [ {"someArrayDoc.Company": "Company1"}, { "someNestedArrayDoc.name": "Nandhi" } ] }
)
```